# SELECT check the colum of the max row

Tags: sql, query-builder, dql

Here my row with my  first select:

```
SELECT 
    user.id, analytic_youtube_demographic.age, 
    analytic_youtube_demographic.percent  
FROM 
    `user`  
INNER JOIN 
    analytic ON analytic.user_id = user.id  
INNER JOIN 
    analytic_youtube_demographic ON analytic_youtube_demographic.analytic_id = analytic.id
```

Result:

```
---------------------------
|   id    | Age | Percent |
|--------------------------
|    1    |13-17|  19,6   |
|    1    |18-24|  38.4   |
|    1    |25-34|  22.5   |
|    1    |35-44|  11.5   |
|    1    |45-54|  5.3    |
|    1    |55-64|  1.6    |
|    1    |65+  |  1.2    |
|    2    |13-17|  10     |
|    2    |18-24|  10     |
|    2    |25-34|  25     |
|    2    |35-44|  5      |
|    2    |45-54|  25     |
|    2    |55-64|  5      |
|    1    |65+  |  20     |
---------------------------
```

The max value by user_id:

```
---------------------------
|   id    | Age | Percent |
|--------------------------
|    1    |18-24|  38.4   |
|    2    |45-54|  25     |
|    2    |25-34|  25     |
---------------------------
```

And I need to filter Age in ['25-34', '65+']

I must have at the end :

```
-----------
|   id    |
|----------
|    2    |
-----------
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Have tried to use `MAX(analytic_youtube_demographic.percent)`. But I don't know how to filter with the age too.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Do you need to return 1 row in the end, which is the highest Age (oldest group)? It's a little hard to follow what you need, but if you added a SELECT TOP 1 to your query, and then added an ORDER BY MAX([Age]), it might give you what you need. Do you mind sharing your full SQL so far? Again, it's a bit hard to follow, but you're close!

Comment: @DanielG No i need to return all rows where the ages are include. Not the highest age but the highest percent.

Comment: @DanielG Like my example : I have 2 user ( id: 1 and id:2 ). 
The max percent is 38.4 for id:1 and 25 for id:2.
Then i need to check that the age of this 2 max percent is include in my rangeAge ( ['25-34', '65+'])

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rank()` function to identify the largest percentage values within each user's data set, and then a simple `WHERE` clause to get those entries that are both of the highest rank and belong to one of the specific demographics you're interested in. Since you can't use windowed functions like `rank()` in a `WHERE` clause, this is a two-step process with a subquery or a CTE. Something like this ought to do it:

```
-- Sample data from the question:
create table [user] (id bigint);
insert [user] values 
    (1), (2);

create table analytic (id bigint, [user_id] bigint);
insert analytic values 
    (1, 1), (2, 2);

create table analytic_youtube_demographic (analytic_id bigint, age varchar(32), [percent] decimal(5, 2));
insert analytic_youtube_demographic values
    (1, '13-17', 19.6),
    (1, '18-24', 38.4),
    (1, '25-34', 22.5),
    (1, '35-44', 11.5),
    (1, '45-54', 5.3),
    (1, '55-64', 1.6),
    (1, '65+', 1.2),
    (2, '13-17', 10),
    (2, '18-24', 10),
    (2, '25-34', 25),
    (2, '35-44', 5),
    (2, '45-54', 25),
    (2, '55-64', 5),
    (2, '65+', 20);

-- First, within the set of records for each user.id, use the rank() function to
-- identify the demographics with the highest percentage.
with RankedDataCTE as
(
    select
        [user].id, 
        youtube.age, 
        youtube.[percent],
        [rank] = rank() over (partition by [user].id order by youtube.[percent] desc)
    from
        [user]
        inner join analytic on analytic.[user_id] = [user].id
        inner join analytic_youtube_demographic youtube on youtube.analytic_id = analytic.id
)
-- Now select only those records that are (a) of the highest rank within their
-- user.id and (b) either the '25-34' or the '65+' age group.
select 
    id,
    age,
    [percent]
from 
    RankedDataCTE 
where
    [rank] = 1 and
    age in ('25-34', '65+');
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your help but this solution is very complicate and im not sure i can't use it on querybuilder. If you have a simple solution. Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: This *is* a simple solution. I'm not familiar with querybuilder; I thought you were asking a SQL question. Maybe updating your question with what you've tried will help illustrate exactly what you're looking for.